# Is there a Stack Exchange site for board game makers?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm looking to create a physical floor-game/game board but would like input from experienced game makers/players. Is there a home on Stack Exchange for that?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ this doesn't sound as an video/computer game. so that dupe doesn't apply.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Board & Card Games Stack Exchange](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/) is full of questions about *playing* board & card games, but it also has a [subsection for *designing* games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-design). Your question might be welcome there, but don't expect them to review your complete design.